# In Ember how can one view be altered when another view is selected?

Tags: ember.js

I'm just starting with Ember and have run into an issue. I'm sure the solution is simple but I can't seem to figure it out! I have several views, when the user clicks in one view I want that view to expand and all other views to shrink. The code is pretty simple, in my html I have

```
{{#each App.Controller}}
    {{#view App.ExpDiv}}
        <!-- some stuff goes here -->
    {{/view}}
{{/each}}
```

In my JS file I have

```
App.ExpDiv = Em.View.extend({
    className:"Exp",

    click: function(){
            this.shrinkAll();
            this.grow();
        }
    },

    shrinkAll: function(){
        //How do I do this?
    },

    grow: function(){
        this.$().animate({ height: "100px" }, 250 );
    }

});
```

The views expand fine but I can't figure out how to access the other views from a click event in the current view. Thanks in advance!

Comment: are your views nested? is `App.ExpDiv` inside another view? and if yes how does your parentview look like (code)...

Comment: @intuitivepixel They aren't nested, currently they are just inside the handlebars script tag.

Comment: I got it to work by setting the App.ExpDiv controllers to a simple controller that kept track of which ones were open/closed by using the controllerBinding command.